# Добавление двух apk arm и x86

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play-console

проект на движке `Unity`, платформа `Android`, подскажите каким образом можно залить в рабочую версию, бету два файла `apk`, с разными архитектурами процессора ?

В статье 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116027/armv7-vs-fat-in-unity-android-build-settings-release-multiple-valid-apks , говорится про расширенный режим, и что `x86` должен иметь код версии выше чем `apk` с `arm`, не могу найти в `play console` где именно этот режим, что позволяет два билда закидывать

При добавлении апк пишет следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один на ARMv7 второй x86, а в результате все равно поддерживают все :) выставлял Device Filter, больше ничего не трогал в настройках
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно переключения такого расширенного режима нет, он работает всегда. Когда добавляете апк, сначала заливаете ARMv7 (например, код версии 1) в окошко, а затем x86 версию (код версии 2). В рабочей версии будет отображаться два апк, будут указаны в чем их разница, их информация и Google Play будет выдавать нужный апк пользователю в зависимости от архитектуры его устройства.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сделал, пишет предупреждение, это нормально, будет корректно работать ? Скриншоты предоставил выше

Comment: @Oliver, проверьте правильные ли вы загрузили АПК. Ошибка о том, что архитектуры совпадают.

Comment: (скрин выше) проверил, всё правильно, но почему то отображается что якобы поддерживают все

Comment: @Oliver, могу только посоветовать заново сбилдить апк с новыми именами, удалить апк версий 30 и 31 из библиотеки Google Play (все загруженные АПК там сохраняются) и попробовать заново, либо если без удаления из библиотеки билдить 32 и 33 коды. Делаете всё правильно, поэтому и в консоли маркета должно быть все правильно.

Comment: так и делал, удалял из библиотеки, имена разные, с приставкой ARM7 и _x86, странно